# Is there a way around a vampire's Sunlight Hypersensitivity?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, undead, damage-resistance

My D&D group decided to attack a group of vampires and I ended up getting bitten and becoming a vampire.

I was playing as a level 15 halfling rogue and had 12 hp left. I was trying to make some distance between me and the vampires. Unfortunately, two more vampires entered the room through a door I ended my turn next to. One of them hit me and the other grappled and bit me... taking me down to 0 hp. I was then used as a health station to for the vampires to keep the fight going.

The DM imposed a houserule related to death: Each turn after being reduced to 0 hp, you lose 1 more hp. Upon reaching -10 hp, you die. I was given a proper funeral and then I rose from a coffin the next night.

Apparently, there aren't any clerics that can cure me.

Player characters transformed into [vampire spawn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/vampire-spawn) gain their traits, including Sunlight Hypersensitivity:

> *Sunlight Hypersensitivity.* The vampire takes 20 radiant damage when it starts its turn in sunlight. While in sunlight, it has disadvantage on attack rolls and ability checks.

**Is there a way to diminish the damage taken from sunlight (i.e. a spell, magic armor, etc.)?**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are only 3 ways for you to reduce radiant damage:

- A Ring of Resistance
- Armor of Resistance
- Potion(s) of Resistance

None of the spells which give resistance to a damage type include radiant as one of their options.

One option (not available to you) is to be a Barbarian and select the Bear Totem for resistance to all damage while raging.

One last possibility: If you can persuade your DM that the damage from Sunlight Hypersensitivity is nonmagical (good luck!), Armor of Invulnerability will give you resistance all the time and immunity some of the time.

You do have some options for avoiding the damage completely, however:

- Avoid being in sunlight (obviously).
- Get cured. There's a few ways to do this, but it's up to you whether the benefits of being a vampire outweigh the drawbacks.
- Don't be a vampire *while in sunlight*. For example, take 2 levels of Druid, and if you know you're going to have to be in sunlight, Wild Shape into something else.

Comment: When you are "Polymorphed" aren't you still a vampire?

Comment: @NightOwl Nope, Polymorph replaces your game statistics with the statistics of the creature you're transformed into - that includes Sunlight Hypersensitivity.

Comment: @Miniman - you could add that to the answer and remove the comment.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to try a vampire character and talked to my DM about it and this is what we worked out:

> I only take damage when in direct sunlight, so as long as I'm in shade I can avoid injury. So to start I'm going to travel with an umbrella.

But again that's something you'd have to work out with your DM